# Order a parent object by a child's property in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How do I order by child objects in LINQ?

Classes A, B, and C.  A has a collection of B and B has a collection of C.  I want to order object A by the Ordinal (int) property of C.

```
var query = from a in db.A
        orderby a.Bs.OrderBy(x=> x.C.Ordinal)   <--- ??
        select a;
```

I can't seem to figure out the orderby statement for this.

EDIT:

Sorry, my original statement was incorrect:

A has a collection of B and B holds a C object.  C is not a collection.

Each A should be ordered on C's ordinal property.

ANOTHER EDIT/Solution:

I ended up doing an .OrderBy(b=>b.C.Ordinal) on the client for each B collection in A during display. That turned out better anyway since I can let the client order by anything they need to, instead of embedding that in my repository.

Comment: You want to order it by Ordinal property of *which* C? The maximum, average, minimum, what exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to work out *which* C you're interested in.

Think of this in terms of real things - if you're trying to order parents by their children's ages, *which* child's age to you take into account? If you have one parent with kids of ages 1 and 5, and one parent with kids of ages 2 and 4, which should come first?

Comment: So what if you want to order by lowest numbers first, parents with kids 2,3,4 before 2,5,8 and then 3,4,5?

Comment: @Dan: If you didn't care beyond the first child, that's easy: `OrderBy(p => p.Children.Min(c => c.Age))`. Ordering by the first child, then the second child etc is trickier to express in LINQ.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going for the trickier version (of course)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552503/order-parent-collection-by-minimum-values-in-child-collection-in-linq

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to order by a Collection. That wont work. You need to either chose one element or aggregate a single value from the child list.

Answer (score 1):

I will apply my american instincts and assume you want to order by the largest C.Ordinal for each A.

```
IEnumerable<A> result = db.As
  .OrderBy(a => a.Bs
    .Max(b => b.C.Ordinal)
  );
```

Edit: updated for "`b.Cs` is not a collection"

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you're looking for exactly, but it may give you some ideas:

.OrderBy( b => b.C.FirstOrDefault().Ordinal)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing an .OrderBy(b=>b.C.Ordinal) on the client for each B collection in A during display. That turned out better anyway since I can let the client order by anything they need to, instead of embedding that in my repository.