# Order parent collection by minimum values in child collection in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
Parent{ List<Child> Children {get;set;} }
Child { int Age {get;set;} }
```

I would like to order the parents by the lowest age of their children, proceeding to the second or third child in the case of a tie.

The closest I've come is this, which only orders by the youngest child:

```
parents.OrderBy(p => p.Children.Min(c => c.Age))
```

This doesn't account for second (or third, etc) youngest in the case of a tie.

Given these 3 parents with corresponding child ages, I'd like them to come out in this order.

- P1 1,2,7
- P2 1,3,6
- P3 1,4,5

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a built-in way to compare IEnumerable<T> (by their elements)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811725/is-there-a-built-in-way-to-compare-ienumerablet-by-their-elements)

Comment: Specifically, you can use the implementation from there as a `Compare` method like so: `parents.OrderBy(p => p.Children.Select(x => x.Age).ToList(), new SequenceComparer<int>())` (where `SequenceComparer<T>.Compare` is the implementation at that link)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you're trying to do, at a conceptual level, is compare two sequences.  Rather than trying to special case it for this specific sequence, we can simply write a comparer capable of comparing any two sequences.

It will go through the items in the sequence compare the items at the same position, and then if it finds a pair that aren't equal, it knows the result.

```
public class SequenceComparer<TSource> : IComparer<IEnumerable<TSource>>
{
    private IComparer<TSource> comparer;
    public SequenceComparer(IComparer<TSource> comparer = null)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<TSource>.Default;
    }
    public int Compare(IEnumerable<TSource> x, IEnumerable<TSource> y)
    {
        return x.Zip(y, (a, b) => comparer.Compare(a, b))
                .Where(n => n != 0)
                .DefaultIfEmpty(x.Count().CompareTo(y.Count()))
                .First();
    }
}
```

Now we can simply use this comparer when calling `OrderBy`:

```
var query = parents.OrderBy(parent => parent.Children
    .OrderBy(child => child.Age)
    .Select(child => child.Age)
    , new SequenceComparer<int>());
```

Comment: +1, that `Compare` function is so neat... I guess except if the sequences are different lengths.

Comment: @Rawling Yeah, you can add `.DefaultIfEmpty(x.Count().CompareTo(y.Count()))` right after the where to cover that case, but that's iterating both sequences twice and fully, which is a lot more work than is needed.  The only alternative would be to scrap the whole LINQ solution and do it all through manual iteration, which I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to write something like this extension method:

```
var orderedParents = parents.OrderBy(p => p.Children, c => c.Age);
```

Generic implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// Given a way to determine a collection of elements (for example
/// children of a parent) and a comparable property of those items
/// (for example age of a child) this orders a collection of elements
/// according to the sorting order of the property of the first element
/// of their respective collections. In case of a tie, fall back to
/// subsequent elements as appropriate.
/// </summary>
public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T, TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<T> @this, Func<T, IEnumerable<TKey>> getKeys, Func<TKey, TValue> getValue)
    where TValue : IComparable<TValue>
{
    return @this.OrderBy(x => x, new KeyComparer<T, TKey, TValue>(getKeys, getValue));
}

private class KeyComparer<T, TKey, TValue> : IComparer<T>
    where TValue : IComparable<TValue>
{
    private Func<T, IEnumerable<TKey>> GetKeys;
    private Func<TKey, TValue> GetValue;

    public KeyComparer(Func<T, IEnumerable<TKey>> getKeys, Func<TKey, TValue> getValue)
    {
        this.GetKeys = getKeys;
        this.GetValue = getValue;
    }

    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        var xKeys = GetKeys(x).OrderBy(GetValue).Select(GetValue);
        var yKeys = GetKeys(y).OrderBy(GetValue).Select(GetValue);

        foreach (var pair in xKeys.Zip(yKeys, Tuple.Create))
        {
            if (pair.Item1.CompareTo(pair.Item2) != 0)
                return pair.Item1.CompareTo(pair.Item2);
        }

        return xKeys.Count().CompareTo(yKeys.Count());
    }
}
```

Comment: The above has been tested on the following data: `A(4,1,2) B(2,4) C(2,2) D()` sorts as `D A C B`

Comment: Nice use of zip. I ran it against my test that checks all edge cases I could think of :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and take the 2nd and 3rd  children.  But, that is not scalable, so it depends on the needs of the impl

If you want something more robust, you could do the following. It will work for this specific case. I am going to see if I can optimize it to be more generic though :)

```
public static class myExt
  {
    public static List<Parent> OrderByWithTieBreaker(this List<Parent> parents, int depth = 0)
    {
      if (depth > parents[0].Children.Count())
        return parents;
      var returnedList = new List<Parent>();

      Func<Parent, int> keySelector = x =>
    {
      IEnumerable<Child> enumerable = x.Children.OrderBy(y => y.Age).Skip(depth);
      if (!enumerable.Any())
        return 0; //If no children left, then return lowest possible age
      return enumerable.Min(z => z.Age);
    };
      var orderedParents = parents.OrderBy(keySelector);
      var groupings = orderedParents.GroupBy(keySelector);
      foreach (var grouping in groupings)
      {
        if (grouping.Count() > 1)
        {
          var innerOrder = grouping.ToList().OrderByWithTieBreaker(depth + 1);
          returnedList = returnedList.Union(innerOrder).ToList();
        }
        else
          returnedList.Add(grouping.First());
      }
      return returnedList;
    }
  }
  [TestFixture]
  public class TestClass
  {
    public class Parent { public string Name { get; set; } public List<Child> Children { get; set; } }
    public class Child { public int Age {get;set;} }

    [Test]
    public void TestName()
    {
      var parents = new List<Parent>
        {
          new Parent{Name="P3", Children = new List<Child>{new Child{Age=1}, new Child{Age=3}, new Child{Age=6}, new Child{Age=7}}},
          new Parent{Name="P4", Children = new List<Child>{new Child{Age=1}, new Child{Age=3}, new Child{Age=6}, new Child{Age=7}}},
          new Parent{Name="P2", Children = new List<Child>{new Child{Age=1}, new Child{Age=3}, new Child{Age=6}}},
          new Parent{Name="P1", Children = new List<Child>{new Child{Age=1}, new Child{Age=2}, new Child{Age=7}}},
          new Parent{Name="P5", Children = new List<Child>{new Child{Age=1}, new Child{Age=4}, new Child{Age=5}}}
        };
      var f = parents.OrderByWithTieBreaker();
      int count = 1;
      foreach (var d in f)
      {
        Assert.That(d.Name, Is.EqualTo("P"+count));
        count++;
      }
    }
```